# Having trouble adding in numbers to the front of an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having trouble with inserting values into an array. I am trying to put in 0 first then 1 then 2, but when I output what the array should look like. It shows as 2, 0, 1. It should have been 2, 1 , 0.

Any help?

```
//add x to front of list
void addFront(THING x)
{
    THING temp;
    if (numarr >= size) {
        //cout <<"Error, you're doing something stupid, out of room" << endl;
        //step 1: create a new, bigger array, copy items over
        resize(2 * size);

        if (numarr != 0) {
            back++;
            temp = myarr[front];
            myarr[front] = x;
            myarr[back] = temp;

            numarr++;
        } else {
            myarr[front] = x;
            numarr++;

        }
    } else {
        if (numarr != 0) {
            back++;
            temp = myarr[front];
            myarr[front] = x;
            numarr++;
            myarr[back] = myarr[numarr];
            myarr[front + 1] = temp;


        } else {
            myarr[front] = x;
            numarr++;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `THING` is not a C++ type I recognize. Is it important to your question? Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your `addFront` moves the first item to the last position in the array every time. I'm sure you can work on with a piece of paper and a pen why you get the results you do.

Comment: You don't have a loop or a recursive call, so obviously you can't move all the elements. Also, don't duplicate all your code between the `if` branch and the `else` branch.